# Loop through chisq.test RStudio

Tags: r, survey, chi-squared

I am trying to perform chisquare tests on about 30 variables. I tried to write a for loop to no luck. The loop should also save the p-value of each test.

I have used this kind of setup before, in other instances, but I recognise that using a vector with the dataframe$variable names does not work on this occasion. I suspect that there is something fundamental I do not understand about the translation from text to variable name.

Example:

```r
survey <- data.frame(
  sex = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1),
  health = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5),
  happiness = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5)
)

variables <- c("survey$health", "data$happiness")
nLoops <- length(variables)

result <- matrix(nrow = nLoops, ncol = 2)

for (i in 1:nLoops){
  test <- chisq.test(variables[i], survey$sex)
  result[, 1] <- test$data.name
  result[, 2] <- test$p.value
}
```

Comment: First of all, this gets borderline to StackOverflow I think, but anyways, can you maybe clarify the goal of your analysis? Is it correct you want to test if sex and health and sex and happiness are independent? Either way, as the error says in your R console, the problem is in the fact that you run a Chi-squared test on the 'variables[i]', which is the string "survey$health", if you can confirm the goal of your analysis, I will provide a working code in the answers!

Comment: This is bound for stackoverflow. But you need to ask them a better question as well. It helps to show what you got and what you want. I can see straight away you forgot to index the last two assignment steps correctly. It should be `result[i, 1] <- test$data.name`. For variables, just set `<- c('health', 'happiness')`. And then it is `survey[,variables[i]]` to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution, changing your for loop to an `lapply` call:

```
lapply (
  c("health", "happiness"),
  function(var) {
    test <- chisq.test(survey[[var]], survey$sex)
    c("name" = paste(var, "vs sex"), "p.val" = test$p.value)
  }
) 
[[1]]
               name               p.val 
    "health vs sex" "0.796763382262977" 

[[2]]
               name               p.val 
 "happiness vs sex" "0.211945584372718" 
Warning messages:
1: In chisq.test(survey[[var]], survey$sex) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
2: In chisq.test(survey[[var]], survey$sex) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The warning messages are caused by your small sample size.

A `tidyverse` solution, which I believe is more robust as it is independent of the names of the columns you wish to analyse.  It can easily be generalised to be robust with respect to your grouping variable as well.

```
library(tidyverse)

survey %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -sex,
    names_to = "Variable",
    values_to = "Value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Variable) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      test <- chisq.test(.x$Value, .x$sex)
      c("name" = paste(.y$Variable, "vs sex"), "p.val" = test$p.value)
    }
  )
```

Results are identical to the above.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with a loop:

```
variables <- c("health", "happiness")
p_values = NULL

for (var in variables){
  test <- chisq.test(survey[var], survey$sex)
  p_values = c(p_values, test$p.value)
}

result = data.frame(variables = variables, p_values = p_values)
result
```

You weren't calling the variables correctly. `"survey$health"` can not be recognised as a data.frame call, it is a character. I also constructed a data.frame for results for a prettier representation.

Also, you could just add `eval(parse(text = "survey$health"))` to your original snippet in order to parse your character in an actual call, but that seems like an over-complication, just use `[]`. I just added that for clarity why your snippet didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom function `my_chi2` in an `lapply` and `rbind`.

```
> my_chi2 <- \(x, y, data=survey, ...) {
+   ct <- chisq.test(data[[x]], data[[y]], ...)
+   ct$data.name <- sprintf('%s and %s', x, y)
+   as.data.frame(ct[c('data.name', 'p.value')])
+ }
```

#### Usage

```
> (res <- lapply(variables, my_chi2, 'sex') |> do.call(what='rbind'))
          data.name   p.value
1    health and sex 0.7967634
2 happiness and sex 0.2119456
Warning messages:
1: In chisq.test(data[[x]], data[[y]], ...) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
2: In chisq.test(data[[x]], data[[y]], ...) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

where

```
> str(res)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ data.name: chr  "health and sex" "happiness and sex"
 $ p.value  : num  0.797 0.212
```

You may pass arguments, e.g.

```
> lapply(variables, my_chi2, 'sex', simulate.p.value=TRUE) |> do.call(what='rbind')
          data.name   p.value
1    health and sex 1.0000000
2 happiness and sex 0.6046977
```

*NB:* If you depend on your `for` loop, you'd need doing,

```
> variables <- c("health", "happiness")
> nLoops <- length(variables)
> result <- matrix(nrow = nLoops, ncol = 2)
> for (i in 1:nLoops) {
+   test <- chisq.test(survey[[variables[i]]], survey$sex)
+   result[i, 1] <- test$data.name
+   result[i, 2] <- test$p.value
+ }
```

but that isn't very R-ish.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(survey)
structure(list(sex = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), health = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5), happiness = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 
2, 3, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
> dput(variables)
c("health", "happiness")
```